# Make a very thin white line in CSS

Tags: css

This may sound quite silly, but I have no idea how to make a thin line smaller then 1px.

What I am looking for is something like this:

https://www.simple.com/

If you do:

```
    .nav-bar {
       border-bottom: 1px;
    }
```

It's almost twice, if not three times as thick. As you are also probably aware, doing `1em` would just round up to `1px`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could create an image that has a line thinner than 1px and then have it be your border.

Comment: The site you link to uses a 1px border. It takes the opacity down to 25% to make it seem like it's smaller. I would try that. Btw, 1px is the lowest measurement you can use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
.nav-bar {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
```

This generates a white 1px line that has an opacity of 25%. This is about the same as your example page. Transparency is the key here; the line can’t be thinner than 1px.

#### Snippet:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.nav-bar {
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-bar">
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use opacity to give the impression that the line is thinner than 1px.

As user @Papa pointed out, 1px is the smallest measurement you can specify:

```
.nav-bar {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this neat trick while I was working on a project, using

```
.div {
    box-shadow: white 0px 0px 1px;
}
```

You can generate a line that appears thinner than a regular 1px line